# How can I disable mouse-drag scrolling on an element with overflow:scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I have a container that holds a chart and I wanted to allow the user to click and drag to pan the chart.  It works fine until the user drags the mouse outside the container and then the chart is scrolled rapidly in the wrong direction.  This seems to be caused by the default scrolling behavior for example if you click and drag in any other element with a scrollbar and drag the mouse out of it, it will begin to scroll.

Is there a way to disable this behavior or some workaround that could make this work?

I only need this to work in chrome (for now at least)

Comment: can you post an example?

Comment: Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/6ruVb/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this site](http://hitconsultants.com/dragscroll_scrollsync/scrollpane.html). They are using a jQuery plugin dragscrollable, which you can look up or get it from the view source on that page.